# No page break after index with idxlayout

Tags: page-breaking, indexing, idxlayout

In the `idxlayout` manual I read that the `memoir` class with `twocolumn` options forces a page break after the index. Is there any way around this behavior? I would like the following to remain on one page, not three.

```
\documentclass[oneside,twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
\makeindex
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \printindex
    \index{Hi}{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you use `twocolumn`, the only way to switch to one column is ejecting a page.

Comment: This is for the break before the index? When changing to columns=2, is still get three pages. I am looking for a small list of to do items just after the title, just before the start of the main text.

Comment: Have you seen the `todo` package?

Comment: Thanks, a dedicated package is probably a better way. I think `fixme` looks nice for my purposes..

Comment: `fixme` is very good for this and very powerful when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `twocolumn` option, the only possible way for switching to a one column format is starting a new page.

You might use the `multicol` package, instead, but probably the best strategy for the problem you're trying to solve is using the `todo` or `fixme` packages.